# Guava - get keys only from left/right and add as ValueDifference

Tags: java, guava

I´m using Guava to compare 2 maps here, but I need to get all new keys from right side and also old keys from left.
Problem is that I need to add them to my object type `Map<String, ValueDifference<Object>>` returned by entriesDiffering() method.

Anyone knows how to do this?
entriesOnlyOnRight/Left give me a Map object and ValueDifference is an interface.

Any help is welcome.
thanks a lot.

Comment: By *new keys from right side and also old keys from left*, do you really mean keys that are in one map but not the other?

Comment: right..objects returned by entriesOnlyOnRight and entriesOnlyOnLeft methods.  ;)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with those methods?

Comment: they give me Map<String, Object> object. Need to add them into a Map<String, ValueDifference<Object>> object, returned by entriesDiffering method.

Comment: *and ValueDifference is an interface* which you can presumably implement.

Comment: nope...it doesn´t have a class that implements it... http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/

Comment: Let me try that again... *and ValueDifference is an interface* which **YOU** can presumably implement.

Comment: but not sure how to store values in this new class. Also, not sure if it´ll work together with ValueDifference

Answer (score 1):

[`ValueDifference`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.ValueDifference.html) only makes sense for entries from both maps containing same key and different values. It does not make sense for `entriesOnlyOnRight()` / `entriesOnlyOnLeft()`, because you know that on the other side there's nothing to compare to.

Let me show you an example:

```
@Test
public void shouldUseMapsDifferenceCorrectly() {
  //given
  ImmutableMap<String, Integer> first = ImmutableMap.of(
      "one", 01, // 1 in octal
      "two", 02, // 2 in octal
      "ten", 010 // 8 in octal
  );
  ImmutableMap<String, Integer> second = ImmutableMap.of(
      "two", 2,
      "three", 3,
      "ten", 10
  );
  //when
  final MapDifference<String, Integer> difference = Maps.difference(first, second);
  //then
  assertThat(difference.areEqual()).isFalse();
  assertThat(difference.entriesDiffering())
      .hasSize(1)
      .hasEntrySatisfying("ten", valueDifference -> {
        assertThat(valueDifference.leftValue()).isEqualTo(8);
        assertThat(valueDifference.rightValue()).isEqualTo(10);
      })
      .hasToString("{ten=(8, 10)}");
  assertThat(difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft())
      .containsExactly(entry("one", 1));
  assertThat(difference.entriesOnlyOnRight())
      .containsExactly(entry("three", 3));
  assertThat(difference.entriesInCommon())
      .containsExactly(entry("two", 2));
}
```

(I used [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html) but the code should be self-explanatory.)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire It's [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html).

Comment: I know that..it doesn´t make sense...but in my app, I´m missing the values that are added / removed from DynamoDB record. That´s why I want to do this trick. ;)

Comment: Can you update the question with sample data you're providing and expected output?